# VMWare Workstation enableSharedFolders error

Tags: vmware-workstation, windows-10

I would like to add a shared folder in vmware-workstation, but the `vmrun` command line is just returning a generic error message.

```
$ vmrun -T ws enableSharedFolders default.vmx
Error: There was an error mounting the Shared Folders file system inside the guest operating system
```

I'm looking first for tips to debug further from here.

How I got here:  I'm running VMWare Workstation `12 Pro` on `Windows 10 Pro` and I'm trying to setup a docker host (which in turn uses the file share for a lot of development sugar).  So the VM image is `boot2docker`.  I'm using a [beta driver](https://github.com/pecigonzalo/docker-machine-vmwareworkstation) for workstation - and it is [internally](https://github.com/pecigonzalo/docker-machine-vmwareworkstation/blob/master/workstation.go#L357) failing on the call to vmrun enableSharedFolders during setup.

Inside the running boot2docker image, I have found `/var/log/vmware-wmsvc.log` to get a few lines each time I run enableSharedFolders - that output looks like:

```
[Jul 05 18:53:21.412] [ message] [vix] ToolsDaemonTcloReceiveVixCommand: additionalError = 17
[Jul 05 18:53:21.413] [ message] [vix] VixTools_ProcessVixCommand: command 62
[Jul 05 18:53:21.413] [ message] [vix] ToolsDaemonTcloReceiveVixCommand: additionalError = 17
[Jul 05 18:53:21.480] [ warning] [vix] ToolsDaemonTcloMountHGFS: vmhgfs-fuse -> 32512
[Jul 05 18:53:21.497] [ warning] [vix] ToolsDaemonTcloMountHGFS: vmhgfs mounting -> 256
[Jul 05 18:53:21.497] [ message] [vix] ToolsDaemonTcloMountHGFS: returning 20050 2
[Jul 05 18:55:41.537] [ message] [vix] VixTools_ProcessVixCommand: command 62
[Jul 05 18:55:41.537] [ message] [vix] ToolsDaemonTcloReceiveVixCommand: additionalError = 17
[Jul 05 18:55:41.537] [ message] [vix] VixTools_ProcessVixCommand: command 62
[Jul 05 18:55:41.537] [ message] [vix] ToolsDaemonTcloReceiveVixCommand: additionalError = 17
```

But I also don't know where to go with that.  Other searching (vmware support mostly) suggests mounting over the network instead of using vmware-tools. I'd like to avoid going down that path to avoid custom users and config on my host.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the latest version of docker-machine using vmware workstation working, thanks to an update from the author.  [Version 1.0.10](https://github.com/pecigonzalo/docker-machine-vmwareworkstation/releases) worked for me.

The main diagnosis I was using, `vmware enableSharedFolders` continues to fail, so that's mysterious, however the `vmhgfs-fuse` based folder mounts *within* the boot2docker vm are working.